# Product of bases of column vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a basis $(X_1,...,X_m)$ for $\mathbb R^m$ and a basis $(Y_1,...,Y_n)$ for $\mathbb R^n$, do the $m\cdot n$ vectors $X_iY_j^t$ form a basis for the vector space $R^{m\times n}$ of all $m\times n$ matrices?

First I tried it out for small $m$ and $n$ using the standard bases and it seems to work. Then I developed a proof using straightforward algebraic manipulation on the standard bases for any $m$ and $n$. But I'm not sure how to generalize this proof for any bases.

This question was not assigned to me for homework but I encountered it while practicing problems from a text book. I think it is appropriate to follow the usual rules for homework questions.

Answer (score 1):

Any number in $\Bbb{R}$ forms a basis for $\Bbb{R}$, and so any matrix with $e_{ij} = a \in \Bbb{R}$ and $=0$ elsewhere, forms a basis for the subspace spanned by it.  Let $e_{ij}$ be your collection of nonzero numbers.  Then each matrix $A$ can be written $\sum_{i,j} A_{ij} e_{ij}$, clearly, so the set spans the linear space of matrices.  Since your space we know is $nm$ dimensional (has the basis $e_{ij} = \delta_{ij} = 1 \iff $i = j$, = 0 $ otherwise.).  Thus any spanning set of size $mn$ is also a basis.

Now to check if your numbers are all positive.

Well, I just now realized your question only makes sense if $n = m$ or else what is $X_i Y_j^t$?

Let $\{X_i: i =1..3\}  = \{(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)\}$, and $\{Y_j\}$ the same, then there exists dot products between elements of the bases that are $0$.  Such you at least need to specify in your hypothesis that the two bases are different or that they're not orthogonal.

Comment: $n$ does not have to equal $m$. $X_iY_j^t$ is just all pairwise combinations of bases vectors. So if $n=2,m=3$ you would have 6 possible combinations of bases vectors.